# ReferenceError: WL is not defined

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8umg.png)

ReferenceError: WL is not defined
mfp 8 version

Comment: Always mention which version of MFP you are using?

Comment: I mentioned right now

Answer (score 1):

This command doesn't compile WL and WLResources:

```
ionic serve
```

Try it:

```
mfpdev app preview
```

Answer (score 0):

Add mfp plugin properly. If already added then remove it and add again.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp
```

Comment: the problem is not resolve. same error is occurring again and again